# simple_read_from_buffer/simple_write_to_buffer vs. copy_to_user/copy_from_user

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I recently wrote a module implementing these functions.

What is the difference between the two?  From my understanding, the `copy_..._user` functions are more secure.  Please correct me if I'm mistaken.

Furthermore, is it a bad idea to mix the two functions in one program? For example, I used `simple_read_from_buffer` in my misc dev `read` function, and `copy_from_user` in my write function.

Edit: I believe I've found the answer to my question from reading `fs/libfs.c` (I wasn't aware that this was where the source code was located for these functions); from my understanding the `simple_...()` functions are essentially a wrapper around the `copy_...()` functions.  I think it was appropriate in my case to use `copy_from_user` for the misc device write function as I needed to validate that the input matched a specific string before returning it to the user buffer.

I will still leave this question open though in case someone has a better explanation or wants to correct me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`simple_read_from_buffer`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.17/source/fs/libfs.c#L756) and [`simple_write_to_buffer`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.17/source/fs/libfs.c#L791) are just convenience wrappers around `copy_{to,from}_user` for when all you need to do is service a `read` from userspace from a kernel buffer, or service a `write` from userspace to a kernel buffer.

> From my understanding, the `copy_..._user` functions are more secure.

Neither version is "more secure" than the other. Whether or not one *might be* more secure depends on the specific use case.

I would say that `simple_{read,write}_...` *could* in general be more secure since they do all the appropriate checks for you before copying. If all you need to do is service a read/write to/from a kernel buffer, then using `simple_{read,write}_...` is surely faster and less error-prone than manually checking and calling `copy_{from,to}_user`.

Here's a good example where those functions would be useful:

```c
#define SZ 1024

static char kernel_buf[SZ];

static ssize_t dummy_read(struct file *filp, char __user *user_buf, size_t n, loff_t *off)
{
        return simple_read_from_buffer(user_buf, n, off, kernel_buf, SZ);
}

static ssize_t dummy_write(struct file *filp, char __user *user_buf, size_t n, loff_t *off)
{
        return simple_write_to_buffer(kernel_buf, SZ, off, user_buf, n);
}
```

---

It's hard to tell what exactly you need without seeing your module's code, but I would say that you can either:

1. Use `copy_{from,to}_user` if you want to control the exact behavior of your function.
2. Use a `return simple_{read,write}_...` if you don't need such fine-grained control and you are ok with just returning the standard values produced by those wrappers.